# Lotus Notes: align entry value into a computed numeric field

Tags: alignment, field, lotus-notes

There is a computed field `Native OS Style`, `width-fixed: 0.409''`, `height - Proportional`.

When its form is composed, it has a default value let say `3`.

I get something like this: where ( `____` is the "length" of the field )

```
3
___
```

Is there any chance to make it like this ?

```
  3
___
```

I read that I need to get to the Text properties ( second tab ) because the field will follow that allignment, but I didn't know how, considering the fact that the field position is ok, I just want to change the value alignment.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about a Notes client app (not a web app).

A "native OS style" field has the text on the left. That's just how these fields work. To get the effect you're looking for, I think you would have to create a "fake" native-style field. Use a table with borders only on the cell containing the field, and in the cell put a Notes-style field but uncheck the option to display field delimiters. Now, if you right-align the cell contents, that will affect the text typed into the field.

If you don't like tables, a "layer" should also work.